# Why I get a "Bad Request" Error 400 when I try to connect with Api with fetch?

Tags: php, reactjs, api

I face a problem with FE/BE integration. When I try to get back an offer object from PHP api I get a 400 error.

I use proxy get to API.

```js
class OfferSite extends Component {
        state = {
                siteId: 1,
                offerId: 4,
                offerDetails: "",

        };

        componentDidMount = () => {

                const data = {
                        "siteId" : this.state.siteId,
                        "offerId" : this.state.offerId,
                };



                fetch('/v1/offers/details', {
                        method: "POST",
                        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
                        body: JSON.stringify({"siteId" : 1, "offerId": 4}),
                })

                    .then((response) => response.json())
                    .then((data) => {
                            this.setState({offerDetails: data});
                            console.log(data);
                            })
        };

        render() {

                return (
                    <div>
                            <OfferCover />
                            <OfferMenu />
                            <OfferHighlights />
                            <OfferMovie />
                            <OfferResort />
                            <OfferAccomodation />
                            <OfferAttractions />
                            <OfferSchedule />
                            <OfferTransport />
                            <OfferCourses />
                            <OfferPrice />
                            <OfferAddons />
                            <OfferTrips />
                    </div>
                )


        }
}

export default OfferSite;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

And this is an error I get:

```
[object%20Module]:1 GET http://localhost:3000/[object%20Module] 400 (Bad Request)
```

I've spent about 6 hours already trying to find solution by myself and will appreciate any help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem:**

---

`Error 400` means that backend server can not process your request. In other words, your request does not follow the rules on backend server.

**Solution:**

---

At a glance, the API call syntax doesn't seem to have a problem. First of all, check your request with [Postman](https://www.postman.com/) to make sure that the API endpoint works properly.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Indeed it was some issue with API. After a slight change everything works properly!